# CKFinder 3 - XML Error at startup

Tags: php, xml, ckfinder

when i'm starting the ckfinder. i get a xml error:

> Es war nicht möglich die XML-Antwort von dem Server herunterzuladen.
>   XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Element gefunden Adresse:
>   http://servername/ordner/assets/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images&CKEditor=editor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=de
>   Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1: ^ Raw-Antwort vom Server:

```
{"enabled":true,"s":"","c":"","thumbs":["150x150","300x300","500x500"],"images":{"max":"1600x1200","sizes":{"small":"480x320","medium":"600x480","large":"800x600"}},"resourceTypes":[{"name":"Images","allowedExtensions":"bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png","deniedExtensions":"","hash":"bd90f11282419614","acl":1023,"maxSize":8388608,"hasChildren":true,"url":"http:\/\/servername\/ordner\/content\/images\/"}],"uploadMaxSize":8388608,"uploadCheckImages":false}
```

What is wrong?
I use CKFinder 3.2.1 (PHP on IIS 8.5)
Thx 4 help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to check you link as it is showing me "Server not found" error.

Invalid XML response may be caused by error in the configuration file or by PHP Warnings / Notices if displaying errors is enabled and error_reporting in set to E_ALL and E_STRICT.

Normally coz of invalid path this error is generated.

Use Firebug to trace ajax calls and check the XML response.

Comment: the server is a private network :)

Firefox shows me the xml error. IE only a blank white page. Chrome works perfect ?! :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your server sends a proper `Content-Type` header in the response, it should be `application/json`.

This may be useful: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx. Please make the the `application/json` MIME Type is configured, and if not, add the following:

- File name extension: `.json`.
- MIME type: `application/json`.

Comment: MIME Type is configured...no effect :(